# removeEventListerner on resize

Tags: javascript

Please suggest, how can I remove the `event listener`.

> On `resize` the screen you will see the data changing

I have the two methods in class `ResponsiveListener`,  `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`.
In the `unsubscribe`, I have tried passing the function reference (I'm not sure if I've done that correctly).

> Expected Behavior: Stop seeing the data change on the screen.

```js
// Add your typescript here
/*
 * 1. Build a class RepsonsiveListener that holds a state map of the browser window.
 * The breakpoints are detailed in the type below.
 *
 * 2. create a "subscribe" method which takes a callback as an argument and dispatches
 * a state update every time the window changes size.
 *
 * 3. Add an unsubscribe button that unsubscribes the subscription
 *
 */

/*
  For Reference:
  - to add a listener to the window to fire an event on resize
  const fn = () => {}
  window.addEventListener('resize', fn);
  - to remove the same listener
  window.removeEventListener('resize', fn);
*/

class ResponsiveListener {
  constructor() {
    this._functionRef = this._functionRef.bind(this);
    this.calculateState = this.calculateState.bind(this);
    this._reference = this._reference.bind(this);
    this.state = this.calculateState();
  }

  // My Attempt Starts here
  
  _functionRef = function (cb) {
    this.state = this.calculateState();
    return cb(this.state);
  };

  _reference = function (cb) {
    return () => this._functionRef(cb);
  };

  _refWithContext = this._reference.bind(this);

  subscribe(cb) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this._refWithContext(cb));
  }

  unsubscribe(cb) {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this._refWithContext(cb), true);
  }
  // Till here
  
  calculateState() {
    const iw = window.innerWidth;
    return {
      extraSmall: iw < 375,
      small: iw >= 375 && iw < 500,
      medium: iw >= 500 && iw < 960,
      large: iw >= 960 && iw < 1280,
      extraLarge: iw >= 1280
    };
  }
}
const responsiveListener = new ResponsiveListener();
const $stateDisplay = document.getElementById("state-display");
$stateDisplay.textContent = JSON.stringify(responsiveListener.state);

const $widthDisplay = document.getElementById("width-display");
$widthDisplay.textContent = String(window.innerWidth);

responsiveListener.subscribe((state) => {
  $stateDisplay.textContent = JSON.stringify(state, null, 2);
  $widthDisplay.textContent = String(window.innerWidth);
});

const $unsubButton = document.getElementById("unsub");

$unsubButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  responsiveListener.unsubscribe((state) => {
    $stateDisplay.textContent = JSON.stringify(state, null, 2);
    $widthDisplay.textContent = String(window.innerWidth);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.2.3/typescript.min.js"></script>
<!-- Enter your HTML code here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Responsive Listener</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre id="width-display"></pre>
  <pre id="state-display"></pre>
  <button id="unsub">unsubscribe</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass the same function to the `removeEventListener`. First because you pass a new callback (*regardless that it has the same code, you should pass reference to the original function*), and secondly because you actually attach the returned value from `this._refWithContext` which will return a new function each time.

My suggestion is to just store the `cb` in the instance and attach a local  method, which will invoke the `cb` when required.

```js
// Add your typescript here
/*
 * 1. Build a class RepsonsiveListener that holds a state map of the browser window.
 * The breakpoints are detailed in the type below.
 *
 * 2. create a "subscribe" method which takes a callback as an argument and dispatches
 * a state update every time the window changes size.
 *
 * 3. Add an unsubscribe button that unsubscribes the subscription
 *
 */

/*
  For Reference:
  - to add a listener to the window to fire an event on resize
  const fn = () => {}
  window.addEventListener('resize', fn);
  - to remove the same listener
  window.removeEventListener('resize', fn);
*/

class ResponsiveListener {
  constructor() {
    this.calculateState = this.calculateState.bind(this);
    this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = this.calculateState();
    this.registeredHandler = null;
  }

  // My Attempt Starts here

  eventHandler(){
    this.state = this.calculateState();
    this.registeredHandler(this.state);
  }

  subscribe(cb) {
    this.registeredHandler = cb;
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.eventHandler);
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.eventHandler);
  }
  // Till here
  
  calculateState() {
    const iw = window.innerWidth;
    return {
      extraSmall: iw < 375,
      small: iw >= 375 && iw < 500,
      medium: iw >= 500 && iw < 960,
      large: iw >= 960 && iw < 1280,
      extraLarge: iw >= 1280
    };
  }
}
const responsiveListener = new ResponsiveListener();
const $stateDisplay = document.getElementById("state-display");
$stateDisplay.textContent = JSON.stringify(responsiveListener.state,null,2);

const $widthDisplay = document.getElementById("width-display");
$widthDisplay.textContent = String(window.innerWidth);

responsiveListener.subscribe((state) => {
  $stateDisplay.textContent = JSON.stringify(state, null, 2);
  $widthDisplay.textContent = String(window.innerWidth);
});

const $unsubButton = document.getElementById("unsub");

$unsubButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  responsiveListener.unsubscribe();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.2.3/typescript.min.js"></script>
<!-- Enter your HTML code here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Responsive Listener</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre id="width-display"></pre>
  <pre id="state-display"></pre>
  <button id="unsub">unsubscribe</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow this is so so so clean, could you please share resources so I can get better at understanding this? I completely understood what your solution is.